# Visual Studio Test Explorer with playlists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, test-explorer

This may be related to question: [Dynamic playlists of unit tests in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512181/are-there-dynamic-playlists-of-unit-tests-in-visual-studio).

I want to be able to have one or more playlists of tests and not have not add every single new test to a certain playlist.

I currently have one playlist containing all my unit tests, but in the future I want to have a playlist consisting of automated integration tests, which should be run before committing to TFS but not every time the application builds.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you use nunit or mstest?

Comment: I use mstest. @nozzleman

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Im not aware of the types of settings you can use in TFS, since Im not using TFS, but I know it is possible using **Categories** in both, **NUnit** and **MSTest**.

### Solution With NUnit

With NUnit, you can mark single tests or even the whole fixtures with a `Category`-Attribute:

```cs
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  [Category("IntegrationTest")]
  public class IntegrationTests
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

or

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  public class IntegrationTests
  {
    [Test]
    [Category("IntegrationTest")]
    public void AnotherIntegrationTest()
    { 
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

and the only run those using nunit-console.exe:

```
nunit-console.exe myTests.dll /include:IntegrationTest
```

### Solution with MSTest

The Solution for MSTest is very similar:

```cs
namespace MSTest.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class IntegrationTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("IntegrationTests")
        public void AnotherIntegrationTest()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But here you have to mark all Tests with that attribute, it cannot be used to decorate the whole class.

Then, like with NUnit, only execute those tests in the *IntegrationTests*-category:

Using **VSTest.Console.exe**

```
Vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory=IntegrationTests
```

Using **MSTest.exe**

```
mstest /testcontainer:myTests.dll /category:"IntegrationTests"
```

### EDIT

You can also execute certain Test-Categories using the TestExplorer of VS.

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC661522.jpeg))</sub>

As seen in the above image, you can select a category in the top left corner of the TestExplorer. Select **Trait** and execute only the catgegory that you want to.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2015) for more Information.

Comment: This is pretty much what I want to do. I managed to run the tests using mstest now. This will run the tests in the command prompt, so I suppose there's no support for this using the built-in Test Explorer in Visual Studio? @nozzleman

Comment: sure there is, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Pretty much the solution I was looking for :)